# How to evaluate $\int \frac{\text{sinc}\left(\sqrt{e^x}\right)}{4a^2} + x^{\phi(p)} \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, contest-math, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals

At my university, some students organized an unofficial integral race. I participated in the final round and emerged as the winner, successfully solving two integrals while my opponent managed to solve only one integral.
This is integral number 6

\begin{align}
\int \frac{\text{sinc}\left(\sqrt{e^x}\right)}{4a^2} + x^{\phi(p)} \, dx
\end{align}

Where $\phi(p)$ is totient function

I have tried but it doesn't work.how do i evaluate it any advice,hint or well thought solution will be appreciated

Comment: Are you sure the differential was $dx$ and not, say, $dy$?

Comment: @Integrand yes I'm sure

Comment: You have $\operatorname{sinc}$ and $\sin(c)$.

Comment: @Aruralreader oh sorry for that  fixed it and this is reason for downvote?

Comment: Don't use the align environment in titles.

Comment: The second integral is just power rule. The exponent is a red herring. The first requires special functions.

Comment: @CameronWilliams sorry for that

Comment: @KalpeshDesai, you reconciled the two integrals so I removed my downvote.

Comment: @Aruralreader oh thanks and any idea hiw to evaluate thr integral

Comment: @CameronWilliams  have any idea how to evaluate the integral ?

Comment: Expand $\operatorname{sinc}$ as a series.

Comment: @Aruralreader $$\text{sinc}\left(e^{\sqrt{x}}\right) = \text{sinc}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{k/2}}{k!}\right)$$

Comment: Expand $\operatorname{sinc}$, not the exponential. You'll get a series of exponential terms, each of which you can integrate easily.

Comment: @Aruralreader $= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n (i^n (1+(-1)^n))}{2(1+n)!}$

Comment: What to do after series expansion ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite the integrand and solve

$$ \int \frac{\sin \sqrt{e^x}}{2a^2 e^x}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{e^x}}{2} + x^{\phi(p)} \: dx = \frac{x^{\phi(p)+1}}{\phi(p)+1}-\frac{\sin\sqrt{e^x}}{2a^2\sqrt{e^x}}+\int\frac{\cos\sqrt{e^x}}{2a^2\sqrt{e^x}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{e^x}}{2}\:dx$$

$$= \boxed{\frac{x^{\phi(p)+1}}{\phi(p)+1}-\frac{\operatorname{sinc}\sqrt{e^x}}{2a^2}+\frac{\operatorname{Ci}\sqrt{e^x}}{2a^2}+C}$$

by integration by parts

Comment: thanks alot sir